# How to handle race condition on Django-Channels consumer?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, race-condition, django-channels, redis-cache

I'm implementing a service with django-channel, I have done some explanations about my issues but you can just scroll down to bottom part where I ask my questions and ignore them.

In this service I'm using a async caching system to raise service's performance.
Writing to this cache raises race condition issues.
Here's two main functions of this cache

```
async def get_room_data_dict(self):
      data = await self.cache_client.get(self.key)
      return data

async def set_room_data_dict(self, room_data_dict):
      is_success = await self.cache_client.set(self.key, room_data_dict)
      return is_success
```

Now here's the problem with this method.

```
### coroutine 1 ###
room_data_dict = await cache_manager.get_room_data_dict()
# In the line below a context switch occurs and coroutine 2 continues to do some tasks
new_room_data_dict = await do_somthing(room_data_dict)
# coroutine 1 continue but room_data_dict is the old one and coroutine 1 going to save it so what coroutine 2 did is actually not applied
await cache_manager.set_room_data_dict(new_room_data_dict)

### coroutine 2 ###
# this coroutine continues without a context switch
room_data_dict = await cache_manager.get_room_data_dict()
new_room_data_dict = await do_somthing(room_data_dict)
await cache_manager.set_room_data_dict(new_room_data_dict)
# gets back to coroutine 1 and continues its code
```

Now if you've looked closely and have some OS education you will see that the change coroutine 2 does on room_data_dict is actually not applied.

Here's the thing I would've done to prevent this problem, I would change the functions like below

```
async def get_room_data_dict(self):
      await self.room_data_dict_semaphore.acquire()
      data = await self.cache_client.get(self.key)
      return data

async def set_room_data_dict(self, room_data_dict):
      is_success = await self.cache_client.set(self.key, room_data_dict)
      self.room_data_dict_semaphore.release()
      return is_success
```

This method would solve my problem if and only if the semaphore in the code is shared in group channel.

### So Here's the things I'm asking and if you can answer any of this I can solve my problem:

1. How can I share an instance of an object between two coroutines (in my problem between two group channels ) ?
2. In python when you do an_instance.str() you get something that shows what is instance's memory address ... Can I get that specific instance with that address ?
3. Any other solutions to my problem other than mine (using semaphores) would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about acquire/release the lock in the outer scope (coroutine 1).

Anyway various locking systems allow you to identify the lock using a string key, so that it can be acquired/released from different scopes. You can even use a distributed lock like python-redis-lock.

Comment: I didn't know about python-redis-lock actually that might be a very good option But about requiring and releasing the lock in the outer scope I should say that what I want is that i have one lock for two coroutines so it's not usable.